# Can I cold condition outdoors?

Tags: bottle-conditioning, first-time-brewer, conditioning

I live in an apartment with a tiny fridge and I cannot afford to use all the space for beer bottles. The average daily high temperature in the region is 6 deg C (42F) while the lows drop down to 1C (33F) with the occasional shower. My beer brewing guide recommends a temperature precisely in that range.

Would it be a terrible idea to cold condition my beer in my balcony provided I make sure to keep it completely dry (sealed in an airtight bag)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep. Just keep it away from sun light. I do this all winter without problems.